# why do i keep getting the message network autoconfiguration failed

Tags: networking

I am unable to install because it says my network is not using the dhcp protocol. I have no idea what that is. There is currently no Os on my computer as I have a brand new hard drive. I am connected to the internet via cable.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP is the protocol that is used to configure networking on a device. It provides a new device with the networking information it needs, such as IP address, netmask, default gateway, DNS servers, and optionally other information such as NTP servers.

The box at the other end of the cable that is plugged in to your computer's ethernet port should be providing this information.